# Extra element at the start of the array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to ask is whats wrong with my code. I'm trying to create a program that checks the number of vowels in a given string and  output it in an array. The problem is there is always an extra element at the start of the array. Why is that happening. There is always a 0 at the start of the array.

Sample output with an input of 18 strings
[0, 8, 13, 5, 8, 12, 7, 5, 3, 9, 8, 8, 16, 11, 15, 10, 9, 9, 9]
I Had to specify that the # of strings is 19 because it add an extra element at the front

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] nums = putArr(in);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    }




    public static int[] putArr(Scanner in){
        System.out.println("How many String");
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int[] make = new int[a];

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            make[i] = vowelCount(in);
        }

        return make;
    }


    public static int vowelCount(Scanner in){
        int count = 0;
        String input = in.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (input.charAt(i) == 'a' || input.charAt(i) == 'e' || input.charAt(i)== 'i' || input.charAt(i) == 'u'
                    || input.charAt(i)== 'o' || input.charAt(i) == 'y'){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `nextLine()` after `nextInt()`. After hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> key it invokes as empty String. Change

```
int a = in.nextInt();
```

To

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

Comment: nextLine() was so it would continue reading the string after a space